Hook has old information and breaks a context
I have an eventEmitter that fires isOnline true or false for when server communications drop. I added 1 if statement to prevent the dispatch firing if the onLine state matches the request to go onLine or offLine. Removing this if fixes the code, but I am stuck with dispatch calls for no reason.
Keep in not this has no issues going from onLine to offLine. It just has issues going from offLine back to onLine.
  const setIsOnline = (isOnline: boolean) => {
    if (state.isOnline !== isOnline) {
      console.log('Online status changed from', state.isOnline, 'to', isOnline);
      dispatch({
        type: navigatorActions.SET_IS_ONLINE,
        payload: isOnline
      });
    }
  };

Here is the reducer for reference. Note the reducer works fine when called. The issue is that if statement prevents it from being called when going online from offline. Taking out the if statement fixes it all, but now I have redundant rerenders.
import {
  navigatorActions,
  NavigatorState
} from '@shared/utils/domains/context/types';

export const navigatorReducer = (state: NavigatorState, action: any) => {
  let updatedState = state;
  switch (action.type) {
    case navigatorActions.SET_BACK_PATH:
      updatedState = { ...state, backPath: action.payload };
      break;
    case navigatorActions.SET_LOGO_CLICKED:
      updatedState = { ...state, logoClicked: action.payload };
      break;
    case navigatorActions.SET_IS_ONLINE:
      console.log('reducer changing', state.isOnline, 'to', action.payload);
      updatedState = { ...state, isOnline: action.payload };
      break;
    default:
      return state;
  }
  return updatedState;
};



What is state.isOnline? Please [edit] to include a complete [mcve] of the relevant code you are working with. That said, I don't see any problem here if your setIsOnline function is unconditionally dispatching the SET_IS_ONLINE action. It's supposed to do that each time the "isOnline" event is emitted, right? If this is a problem then I suspect you can work your way either direction, either not unnecessarily emitting extraneous "isOnline" events or simply ignoring SET_IS_ONLINE actions that don't matter.

Request.ts sends an eventEmitter everytime a good returhn comes back to setIsOnline. These work, but it generates rerenders if they always run so I want the if statement to only dispatch when a change occurs. For some reason the state.isOnLine and isOnline boolean sent to the function match each other after the event fires false the first time so any true will not change it back to true.

Dispatching the action isn't what triggers a React component rerender though.

With the incomplete code example my guess here is that you've a stale Javascript closure over state.isOnline in the setIsOnline handler.
Instead of trying to work around JS closures I suggest just handling the "is online" comparison in the reducer function. Dispatching an action isn't what triggers a React component rerender. The SET_IS_ONLINE reducer case is unconditionally creating a new state object and this is what is very likely triggering "unnecessary" component state updates.
Update the reducer logic to compare the current state.isOnline value to the incoming action.payload value and only update the state if the value will actually change.
Example:
const setIsOnline = (isOnline: boolean) => {
  dispatch({
    type: navigatorActions.SET_IS_ONLINE,
    payload: isOnline
  });
};

export const navigatorReducer = (state: NavigatorState, action: any) => {
  let updatedState = state;
  switch (action.type) {
    case navigatorActions.SET_BACK_PATH:
      return { ...state, backPath: action.payload };

    case navigatorActions.SET_LOGO_CLICKED:
      return { ...state, logoClicked: action.payload };

    case navigatorActions.SET_IS_ONLINE:
      // isOnline will change, return new state
      if (state.isOnline !== action.payload) {
        return { ...state, isOnline: action.payload };
      }

      // no isOnline change, return current state
      return state;

    default:
      return state;
  }
};

